# How to make a Javascript function start when a DIV element is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, function, animation

I have a single-page html application. There is only one thml file that has multiple DIVs, that are displayed/hidden when the relevant button is clicked.

I use some animation on one of this DIVs (not on the "first page DIV"). The problem is that the animation starts directly when  the html document is loaded and vhen i go to that div with the animation, the animation is already ended.

My question is: How to make the animation start just at the moment when it's DIV is displayed?

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var o, qt=[
        ["a","b","c"],
        ["d","e","f"],
        ["g","h","i"]];

    o=document.getElementById("quote1");
    o.innerHTML="";
    for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
        o.innerHTML+="<p id=\"quote1_"+i+"\" style=\"font-size: 28pt;\">&nbsp;</p>";

    var q=qt[Math.floor(Math.random() * qt.length)];
    document.getElementById("quote1_1").innerHTML=q[0];
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("quote1_2").innerHTML=q[1]; }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("quote1_3").innerHTML=q[2]; }, 3000);
}

window.onload = function(){
   myFunction();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Page1">
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<center>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">SHOW ANIMATION</a>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>




<div id="Page2" style="display:none">
<div data-role="page" id="main">
<div data-role="content">
<center>
<div id="quote1"></div>
<center>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Next</a>
</center>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript, you can use the `MutationObserver`. Yet using libraries like angularjs or knockoutjs should be much simpler. The `MutationObserver` is quite complicated in my opinion. One way to do that when the `MutationObserver` didn't exist yet was to track object creation. When you create an object in the dom, you can trigger the callback. The only big problem with this method is that it wouldn't work for changes to the dom that aren't explicitly tracked. The `MutationObserver` will catch any change to the DOM by user interaction or not.

In your case, a simple solution would be to execute something right after you added it to the dom.

Something like that:

```
function changeElement(target, source, callback) {
  target.innerHTML = source;
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(target);
  }, 0);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    changeElement(document.getElementById("quote1_2"), q[1], function (parent) {
       // code here
    }
}, 2000);
```

You could also change the function above to already include the `setTimeout` to make it cleaner.

```
function changeElement(target, source, callback, wait) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    target.innerHTML = source;
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(target);
    }, 0);
  }, wait);
}

changeElement(document.getElementById("quote1_2"), q[1], function (parent) {
  // code here
}, 2000);
```

The `setTimeout` with 0 is to make sure the code is executed after the `innerHTML` gets updated. It's possible that if you execute directly the callback, the dom won't be already available in the callback.

---

As for animation, you should have a look to css3 transitions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions The animations can be done by making opacity modified itself slowly for example. It really depends on what you want to do.

---

## MutationObserver

This is a way to do what you're trying to do. MutationObserver isn't that easy to setup. I did a small example:

```
var target = window.container;

function changeOpacity(target) {
    setTimeout(function(){   
        target.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 100);
}

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
       console.log(mutation);
      if (mutation.type == "childList") {
          for(var i=0; i<mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
              changeOpacity(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
          }
      }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

setTimeout(function () {
    target.innerHTML = "<div class='elem'>Some text</div>";
}, 2000);
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8zmc8/

Comment: Would like to point out this **is** possible in pure JavaScript. If it wasn't you couldn't do it with any libraries either.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek apparently there are now.. MutationEvents exists but I guess tracking element creation should be still the best way than cluttering the document with events.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Kcent's post, there is also a plugin for jQuery called "ScrollMagic":

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

It activates animations depending on scroll speed/placement on the page. 
You can find the documentation here:

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jQuery, there's a library called waypoints that handles this very problem: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

The core of what you are looking for is:
- adding an event listener to the window scroll
- listening for the offsetTop of the target div to come into view
- and then trigger the animation at the desired offsetTop value